# React Router conditional redirect

Tags: redirect, react-router-dom, reactivesearch

I'm building a search UI using React, React Router and the awesome [Reactivesearch](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactivesearch/) library. I'm trying to figure out how I can prevent users from simply navigating to **mydomain.com/search**, since that is my search results route.

Ideally, if users tried to navigate to mydomain.com/search, I will use RR Redirect component to redirect to the home page.

I'm using `"/search"` for the route that the Route component in RR(v5) to render the search results page and can't quite figure out how to use something like `/search?q=${value}` to render the page?

As a preface I do have this in the render block (I'm using class based component for search results)

```
let value = JSON.stringify(queryString.parse(location.search));
if (this.value === '' || null) {
       return (
         <Redirect to="/" />
       );
     }
```

However, its not working... I can still go to my address bar and type in mydomain.com/search and the page renders.

Here is an example in my SearchResults.tsx:

```
<Route path = "/search" render={() => (
   <ReactiveList
    ...
    ...
    />
   />
```

I'm trying to get to

```
<Route path = `/search?q="${value}"` render={() => (
   <ReactiveList
    ...
    ...
    />
   />
```

**Update**
Docs on [ReactiveList](https://docs.appbase.io/docs/reactivesearch/v3/result/reactivelist/)
Example from docs:

```
<ReactiveList
    componentId="SearchResult"
    dataField="ratings"
    pagination={false}
    paginationAt="bottom"
    pages={5}
    sortBy="desc"
    size={10}
    loader="Loading Results.."
    showResultStats={true}
    renderItem={res => <div>{res.title}</div>}
    renderResultStats={function(stats) {
        return `Showing ${stats.displayedResults} of total ${stats.numberOfResults} in ${
            stats.time
        } ms`;
    }}
    react={{
        and: ['CitySensor', 'SearchSensor'],
    }}
/>
```

How can I prevent users from simply navigating to mydomain.com/search ??

Comment: `react-router-dom` route components deal only with the URL path for route matching and rendering. You'll need to ready any queryString parameters in the routed component and handle any redirection there. Can you update your question to include a more complete and comprehensive code example ([mcve]), specifically this `ReactiveList` component?

Comment: @DrewReese so it sounds like your saying I may need to implement something like a Result HOC that would check for query string params and anything else that needs to be present in order for that route to render? I also added an update about ReactiveList

Comment: A HOC might work, but I was thinking something more along the lines of a wrapper component, or just checking directly in the component itself. Is `ReactiveList` a 3rd-party component, i.e. something you don't own? If this is the case, then yes, you'd need to wrap/decorate it with a component that can handle the logic of reading any query params and act accordingly. You just want to only render the `ReactiveList` component if there is a `q` query param, otherwise redirect somewhere or issue a back navigation? Would you like examples?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes and no with ReactiveList. Its part of a 3rd party search UI lib that I use. It is highly configurable but ultimately it interacts with a 3rd party search api that I don't own.  Yes I would love an example where there is a q query param present, otherwise direct back home or back navigation!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to conditionally render the `ReactiveList` component based on if there's a truthy `q` queryString parameter then you can use either a wrapper component, a layout route, or a Higher Order Component (HOC) to read the queryString and handle the redirection logic.

### `react-router-dom@6`

#### Using a Wrapper

```
import { Navigate, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const QuaryParametersWrapper = ({ children, parameters = [] }) => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const hasParameter = parameters.some(
    (parameter) => !!searchParams.get(parameter)
  );

  return hasParameter ? children : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
};
```

...

```
<Route
  path="/search"
  element={(
    <ReactiveListWrapper parameters={["q"]}>
      <ReactiveList
        ...
        ...
      />
    </ReactiveListWrapper>
  )}
/>
```

#### Using a custom HOC

```
import { Navigate, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const withQueryParameters = (...parameters) => (Component) => (props) => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const hasParameter = parameters.some(
    (parameter) => !!searchParams.get(parameter)
  );

  return hasParameter ? <Component {...props} /> : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
};
```

...

```
export default withQueryParameters("q")(ReactiveList);
```

...

```
import ReactiveListWrapper from '../path/to/ReactiveList';

...

<Route path="/search" element={<ReactiveListWrapper />} />
```

#### Using a layout route

```
import { Navigate, Outlet, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const QuaryParametersLayout = ({ parameters = [] }) => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const hasParameter = parameters.some(
    (parameter) => !!searchParams.get(parameter)
  );

  return hasParameter ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
};
```

...

```
<Route element={<QuaryParametersLayout parameters={["q"]} />}>
  <Route path="/search" element={<ReactiveList />} />
</Route>
```

#### Demo

[image: Edit react-router-conditional-redirect]

### `react-router-dom@5`

The `useSearchParams` hook doesn't exist in v5 so you can create your own.

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const useSearchParams = () => {
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const searchParams = useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(search), [search]);
  return [searchParams];
};
```

#### Using a Wrapper

```
import useSearchParams from '../path/to/useSearchParams';

const QuaryParametersWrapper = ({ children, parameters = [] }) => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const hasParameter = parameters.some(
    (parameter) => !!searchParams.get(parameter)
  );

  return hasParameter ? children : <Redirect to="/" />;
};
```

...

```
<Route
  path="/search1"
  render={(routeProps) => (
    <QuaryParametersWrapper parameters={["q"]}>
      <ReactiveList {...routeProps} />
    </QuaryParametersWrapper>
  )}
/>
```

#### Using a custom HOC

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import useSearchParams from '../path/to/useSearchParams';

const withQueryParameters = (...parameters) => (Component) => (props) => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const hasParameter = parameters.some(
    (parameter) => !!searchParams.get(parameter)
  );

  return hasParameter ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />;
};
```

...

```
export default withQueryParameters("q")(ReactiveList);
```

...

```
import ReactiveListWrapper from '../path/to/ReactiveList';

...

<Route path="/search2" component={QueryReactiveList} />
```

#### Demo

[image: Edit react-router-conditional-redirect (RRDv5)]

Comment: Thanks! I'm just now getting to it and will accept it as soon as I have it working. I'm still am on RR v5 so I'm guessing I can replace element with component and Navigate with Redirect?

Comment: @user3125823 Oh, my bad... totally missed the fact that you are using RRDv5. I'll update with a v5 version of this answer.

Comment: really appreciate the detailed answer. I worked on this problem for probably a week or so until I fully understood it and was then able to use your HOC code to solve it. Up until now I hadn't fully understood the whole query params deal with RR - now I do!!

Comment: @user3125823 Sure thing, glad to help! Cheers and good luck!